# Setting macros for letters and other symbols in C?

Tags: c, macros, printf, character

I just wondered, is there a way to define a macro in C to replace it for certain symbols that I print ? I tried something similar to defining number values, like `#define NUMBER 7`, but I haven't managed to do the same for characters. Googling hasn't given me a proper answer either. Is something like defining characters by macros even a  thing in C ? Thanks for your advice !

Comment: Please show a [mre] of your attempt for letters. I suspect a problem with `""` or `''`. I guess that you e.g. try to `printf()` one of your macroed letters. Show that and I think any problem you encounter might be solved. The solution however might defeat the purpose of your macro, because I guess you will consider it less readable and longer, than without macros ...

Comment: Macros do text replacement. It does not matter if that text is `7`, `'7'` or `"seven"`. Everything depends on the way you intent to use that macro in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define mystr "HELLO WORLD"

int main()
{
    printf("%s", mystr);

    return 0;
}
```